# Проблема с позиционированием формы

Tags: html, css

Не могу сдвинуть форму в это место.
Надо сделать вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<footer>
  <div class="container clearfix">
      <nav class="footnav">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact us</li>
    </nav>
    <div class="contus">
      <h2>Contact us</h2>
    </div>
          <form>
          <div class="left">
          <label>Subject:</label>
          <input type="text"></input>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input type="text"></input>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom">
          <label>Your Message:</label>
          <input type="text"></input>
          </div>
         </form>
    <div class="ouradd">
      <h3>Our Addres</h3>
      <p>House No,11132, Sector 31, Gurgaon<br> 
       122001  India</p>
    </div>
      <div class="callus">
      <h3>CALL US</h3>
      <p>+ 91-9876543210<br>+ 01262219018</p>
      </div>
       <div class="emailus">
      <h3>email us</h3>
      <p>contactus@email.com</p>
       </div>
       </div>
  </footer>

footer {
  background-color: #3b404c;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  color: white;
}
footer nav {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
footer nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
footer h2 {
  font-size: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}
footer h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
footer .ouradd {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
footer .callus {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
footer .emailus {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}
form label {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
form input {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #7a7b7f;
}
form input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00a5ff;
}
form .right {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
form .left {
  float: right;
}
form .bottom {
  margin-top: 114px;
}
form .bottom input {
  width: 420px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый наипростейщий способ, не передергивая уже имеющуюся верстку - добавить форме обтекание

```
form {
  float: right;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}
```

`display: inline-block` убрал, так как при `float` любой элемент автоматически становится блочным.

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался))